# Argument of CanvasRenderingContext2D.getImageData is not a finite floating-point value

Tags: javascript, изображения, canvas

Я новичок в работе с canvas, прошу помочь. Использую метод getImageData() для получения массива данных из изображения.
JavaScript-код представлен ниже:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('c1');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.fillRect(100,50,150,75);

var pixel = ctx.getImageData(0,0, ctx.width, ctx.height);
console.log(pixel);
```

HTML-код

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <script src="js.js" defer></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="c1"></canvas>
    </body>
</html>
```

в консоли выдает следующую ошибку "Argument 3 of CanvasRenderingContext2D.getImageData is not a finite floating-point value" . Аргумент 3 не является конечным значением с плавающей точкой. Как привести аргументы к типу float?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь получить `width` и `height` `ctx`, а надо `canvas`!

```
var pixel = ctx.getImageData(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height); // ЗДЕСЬ
```

Можно так глянуть все не 0:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('c1');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.fillRect(100,50,150,75);

var pixel = ctx.getImageData(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
var notZero = pixel.data.filter(v => v); // Все значения не 0, 0 = false

console.log(notZero);
```

```html
<canvas id="c1"></canvas>
```

Comment: Спасибо, а можно у Вас спросить, почему метод в данном случае возвращает только 0?

Comment: Все нормально он возвращает) Открой огроменный массив data и поищи, где не ноль, а 255

Comment: Странно, конечно, просмотрел весь массив, но везде 0

Comment: Проиграй этот код: НАЖМИ ВЫПОЛНИТЬ КОД